# element's css attributes differenent from the ones defined

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I have been trying to incorporate a search bar(http://loopj.com/) in a drupal website I am developing. While I define the width of a element as 400px in the following way:

```
ul.token-input-list {
overflow: hidden; 
height: auto !important; 
height: 1%;
width: 400px;
border: 1px solid #8496ba;
cursor: text;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Verdana;
min-height: 1px;
z-index: 999;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #fff;
list-style-type: none;
clear: left;
```

}

This results into having an offset to my pointer that I cannot remove. 
So I guess that being able to sort of deactivate inherited attributes would do the job, any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add !important in front of your css property ,

```
Ex:-
padding: 0!important ;
```

etc...

Comment: Right on target ;) Thanks userxxx :-)